# Directly download font package instead of using <link href="" rel="stylesheet">

Tags: html, css, fonts

I won't be able to access internet on our hosting servers so I'm wondering if there's a way to download directly the font file instead of linking to the style sheet.

```
<style>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</style>
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: perhaps download the file, store it locally, and then set href link to the local address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Fonts has a "**Download family**" button atop each font page that provides a ZIP file with TTFs in each weight. Here's the page for Montserrat, the font used in your example: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat

Using those files, you can set up your own local stylesheet that references the TTF files using `@font-face` rules, like the example below.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  src: url("/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf") format("ttf"),
}
```

Learn more, including how to assign different weights to variants like bold, at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) and [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/).